# Call Twilio Client from Twimlet

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Dialing a Twilio client app requires the `<client>` twiml noun. Is there a way to generate the Twiml necessary to forward a call to a client using a Twimlet? Ideally, the simulring would accept client OR numbers, but it does not appear to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to simulring a mixture of clients

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial callerId="+1234567890">
    <Client>Bob</Client>
    <Client>Steve</Client>
    <Client>Ted</Client>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Remember that you must provide a valid callerId when calling out to a client or the call will fail.

If you want something like the sumulring TwiMLet you can host this code by pasting your TiwML into the Echo TwiMLet https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo or by using TwiMLbin http://twimlbin.com/.

Comment: I got it working.  You have to be careful with double URL encoding, and I think that was my issue. I pasted a 'raw' echo URL and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up to this, this is NOT working: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Response>
    <Dial action="/simulring?Dial=true" callerId="2515551212">        <Client>regretoverflow</Client>        <Number>2515551213</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>`
Should I be able to dial a client and number simultaneously?